# Maven Dependency for com.install4j.install4j-runtime

Tags: maven-3, install4j

I am using below maven dependency for com.install4j.install4j-runtime

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.install4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>install4j-runtime</artifactId>
     <version>6.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Version is not valid.

Can any one help me is resolving the dependency?

Comment: Have you added the repository http://maven.ej-technologies.com/repository ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the repository:

```
<repository>
   <id>ej-technologies</id>
   <url>http://maven.ej-technologies.com/repository</url>
</repository>
```

to your POM.